# add white padding when concatenating images in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

The code below concatenates images horizontally but adds a black padding. How can I make it add a white padding?

```
ffmpeg -i %0d.png -filter_complex scale=240:-1,tile=5x1:padding=10 output.png
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the color option. See the [docs](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#tile-1).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1067292)

Comment: The first sentence is the self-contained answer. The 2nd sentence is for reference and I maintain the docs, so I'll change the link if it does.